# distributing an iPad app during development?

Tags: iphone, ipad

So I got my app up and running on my iPad so I can test it before submitting it for provisioning in the app store.  Sweet.  Is it possible for me to get the app installed on other iPad's for testing during this phase of development?  I have a client who will be using the app and I'd like them to be able to run through it while we iron out the kinks.

Comment: Is the client a developer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple call this "ad hoc distribution".

There are many guides around, eg: http://bluxte.net/musings/2009/05/17/ad-hoc-distribution-iphone-application. As Marcelo said, you'll need the udid from the ipad - this can be seen in itunes, connect the device and click on the 'serial number' field under the device summary.

It is a lot easier using the most recent versions of xcode - once you have the certificates sorted out, there's a "build and share" feature in xcode that'll build the necessary .ipa file and automatically attach it to an email. To get to this, use the "build and archive" entry in the 'build' menu, then in the organizer window, select 'archived applications', then the date you just built, then 'share application....', then 'email...'.

Comment: how do I get to this "build and share" option?

Comment: Ah, sorry - it's not entirely obvious - I've updated my answer to describe it. Start from the 'build and archive' option basically.

Answer (score 0):

Add their device(s) to your provisioning portal, then send them the app along with the provisioning certificate. They'll need to supply you a UDID, which they can do via the free UDID app on the App Store.